# How to make frosting very white, fluffy, and shiny?

Tags: ingredient-selection, frosting

**Given a typical recipe for frosting *(preferably cream cheese)*, what can be done to make it fluffy and shiny -- even in a chilled state?**

I've noticed that my cream cheese frosting tends to do this if I put it in the refrigerator. I'm wondering if there is **a technique** *(e.g. beat in a lot of air in it)* or **ingredient** *(e.g. corn syrup/glucose???)* that would help.

**Also, how can I make mine super white?** The frosting I make is a bit yellowish -- probably due to the cream cheese already having some color. The vanilla also probably adds to the color.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://bakingamoment.com/magical-cream-cheese-frosting/ while you consider Cindy's adaptations. Also, if butter adds too much color but you still want the flavor, consider a clear [extract](http://www.wilton.com/store/site/product.cfm?id=3E30D7E5-475A-BAC0-55409D432277491E) for that as well as the clear vanilla.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

1. To make the frosting whiter:

   - If you use butter, eliminate it. Use all of the other standard ingredients but substitute heavy whipping cream for the butter. Add until you have the consistency you want.
   - While I can't say I would do this, a viable option would be to substitute a good brand of vegetable shortening for the butter.
   - Rather than pure vanilla you may consider imitation clear vanilla.
   - Try adding white food coloring. Regarding food coloring I would recommend a good gel or soft gel/paste formula.
2. To make the frosting shinier:

   - If you use butter in your frosting you can try adding more butter.
   - While I have never cooked cream cheese frosting, there are recipes available online that use corn syrup or glucose syrup and are supposed to produce excellent results in regard to gloss.
   - After you finish frosting your cake, take a butter knife (non-serrated) or metal frosting spatula and dip in hot water and dry. Go over the frosting again dipping the knife as needed. This should melt the very outside of the frosting only creating the gloss you want.

Comment: white food coloring !? mind blown.

Comment: @TJEllis [White-White](http://www.wilton.com/store/site/product.cfm?sku=603-1236) "White-white is used for lightening icing that has been colored too dark. Also use it for making white buttercream made with butter or margarine."

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to use a different kind of frosting you can use egg white frosting. It is super white.

- Whisk egg white
- Add ice sugar until consistance is creamy. You might need an important amount of sugar to make it thick enough. I don't have numbers here, I usally add progressively until good.
- Apply
- Let dry. It can be long for thick layer.